# How to list all current smb connections - even those without drive letter?

Tags: c#, windows, connection, unc, smb

I am looking for a way to list all `smb connections` (hostnames of the remote servers), that are established on a windows client.

Connections to servers `wihout assigned drive letter` should also be shown. The code is running on the client.

Is there a way to do that without wmi?